# How to route requests to an internal address to localhost

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I have just moved from one hosting environment to another, and my networking has changed somewhat.

Previously, requests from a server to its own external IP address were routed to localhost and the ping times were indistinguishable from pinging localhost:

```
wg@akl2:~$ ping akl2.wb.gs
PING akl2.wb.gs (112.109.67.244) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from akl2.wb.gs (112.109.67.244): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from akl2.wb.gs (112.109.67.244): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
[...]
wg@akl2:~$ ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
```

Now I'm in an OpenStack environment, and the ping times are very different:

```
ubuntu@legacy1:~$ ping legacy1.webgenius.co.nz
PING legacy1.webgenius.co.nz (103.250.241.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 103-250-241-12.rev.nz-hlz-1.catalystcloud.nz (103.250.241.12): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.912 ms
64 bytes from 103-250-241-12.rev.nz-hlz-1.catalystcloud.nz (103.250.241.12): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.643 ms
[...]
ubuntu@legacy1:~$ ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
```

The above two requests should be completely local, as in they should not leave the machine.

How can I route those requests to the local interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is in the latter case, `103.250.241.12` isn't directly configured on the server (as in, if you run `ip a`, you'll probably see a private IP instead of the aforementioned IP), even if the IP is dedicated to it by 1:1 NAT.

If my guess is true, and `103.250.241.12` is not (too) *ephemeral*, you can consider:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -d 103.250.241.12 -j REDIRECT
```

See [iptables-extensions(8)](https://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) for details.

Comment: Legend! That worked nicely, thanks heaps. For a bonus point, any ideas how to make it work inside a Docker container?  

Comment: `inside a Docker container` is vague, since you can have different networking mode and different kind of setups. If you need the container itself to responds to the requests (to `103.250.241.12`), then you should probably just add the iptables rule in the container. If you want the container host to responds to the requests (to `103.250.241.12`) from its containers, then you might want something like `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i name_of_the_docker_bridge -d 103.250.241.12 -j REDIRECT` on the host (assuming you are using a forwarded/NAT'd bridge setup).

Comment: I just ran the same command inside the container and it worked nicely, not sure why I didn't think of that... Thanks again! I'll buy you a beer some time.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer:

If all requests are made by hostname, you can also add `legacy1.webgenius.co.nz` to `/etc/hosts` and have it resolve to `127.0.0.1`. No iptables needed.

And do check `ip addr` as recommended.